# How to plot the number of publications versus Year. is there a way using python or Bibtex?

Tags: python, plot, latex

i have the publication references in a .bib file.  How to plot the number of publications versus Year.  is there a way using python or Bibtex?

Comment: I suggest to have a look at biblatex: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66868